# Built-in display stopped working - The screen can't be detected after boot on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, nvidia, multiple-monitors, bug-reporting, detect

I'm facing a new issue after trying to solve the NVIDIA brightness issue.

My external monitor is working as expected but the built-in monitor is showing a black screen with an error and it is not being detected by the system!

[image]

The message shown on the built-in screen is the following:

```
x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_GPE._L12], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psobject-220)
ACPI ERROR: For GPE 0x08, found both _L08 and _E08 methods (20221020/evgpeinit-398)
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 6894067/31227904 files, 55499909/124895488 blocks
```

[image]

If you have any idea on how to fix this problem please let me know, It will be really appreciated;

Regards,
Leonardo